# Why don't app shortcuts' icons get updated when installing new versions?

Tags: android, icons, updates, shortcut, android-launcher

### Background

I have an app-manager app ([**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)), which, amongst other features, can create shortcuts to other apps on the launcher.

### The problem

It seems that shortcuts that were created by my app don't get their icons updated when installing new versions of those apps.

I've noticed it on multiple devices and multiple launchers.
Not only that, but even icons that the play store creates don't get updated.

Not only that, but on some launchers, when trying to create a shortcut, if there is already one, it fails to create a new one.

### What I've tried

I've tested it not only with normal apps, but also on my own signed APKs, via both ADB and via normal opening of the APK files (while also making sure the versions is increased.

There are 3 ways to create a shortcut, but all failed for me in getting updated:

1. adding a shortcut with an icon res id:

   ```
   Intent shortcutIntent;
   shortcutIntent=new Intent();
   //    shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate",false);  //optional
   shortcutIntent.setClassName(packageName,fullPathToActivity);
   shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   final Intent putShortCutIntent=new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
   putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,shortcutIntent);
   putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,title);
   Resources resources=pm.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
   final Intent launchIntentForPackage=pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
   if(TextUtils.equals(launchIntentForPackage.getComponent().getClassName(),fullPathToActivity))
     iconRes=applicationInfo.icon;
   else
     iconRes=pm.getActivityInfo(new ComponentName(packageName,fullPathToActivity),0).icon;
   if(iconRes==0)
     iconRes=applicationInfo.icon;
   String iconResourceName=resources.getResourceName(iconRes);
   putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,iconRes);
   ```
2. same as the above, but using a bitmap for the icon:

   ```
   ...
   Bitmap appIcon=...
   putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON,appIcon);
   ```
3. same as the above, but using ShortcutIconResource instead:

   ```
   ...
   ShortcutIconResource shortcutIconResource=new Intent.ShortcutIconResource();
   shortcutIconResource.packageName=packageName;
   shortcutIconResource.resourceName=iconResourceName;
   putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,shortcutIconResource);
   ```

### The question

Why is it that launchers don't update my shortcuts, and some of them (or all) don't even update when they were created from the Play Store ?

What is the correct way to create shortcuts, that will get updated upon replacing/updating of apps?

Also, why do most launchers ignore adding a shortcut if it's already shown?